# bazel - Error building TensorFlow with local LLVM repository

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

Essentially, I want to run TensorFlow with a custom LLVM repository and not the llvm-mirror that bazel pulls from.

I made the following changes:

1. Changed the `temp_workaround_http_archive` rule in `//tensorflow/workspace.bzl` to:

   ```
     native.local_repository (
       name = "llvm",
       path = "/git/llvm/",
     )
   ```
2. In `/git/llvm` I added the file `WORKSPACE` containing:

   ```
     workspace( name = "llvm" )
   ```

However, I know that an `llvm.build` file is required, but since I am new to bazel, I am not sure where it should be located.

I am getting the following error log:

```
bazel build --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
ERROR: /git/tensorflow/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/BUILD:81:1: no such package '@llvm//': BUILD file not found on package path and referenced by '//tensorflow/tools/pip_package:licenses'.
ERROR: Analysis of target '//tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package' failed; build aborted.
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.219s
```

I installed TensorFlow from source. Here is the version info:

```
$ git rev-parse HEAD
4c3bb1aeb7bb46bea35036433742a720f39ce348

$ bazel version
Build label: 0.4.5
Build target: bazel-out/local-fastbuild/bin/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/bazel/BazelServer_deploy.jar
Build time: Thu Mar 16 12:19:38 2017 (1489666778)
Build timestamp: 1489666778
Build timestamp as int: 1489666778
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the fix. Quite simple actually.

The `local_repository` rule in bazel is for external bazel repositories only. To use a non-bazel external repository, we need to use `new_local_repository` which takes `build_file` as an argument.

Comment: I met the same problem when I was attempting to use a local repository for LLVM due to desperate connectivity. I tried 1. commenting out `http_archive` of llvm in `tensorflow/workspace.bzl`, 2. adding `new_local_repository(name = "llvm",build_file = "third_party/llvm/llvm.BUILD",path = 'llvm_local/')` to `tensorflow/WORKSPACE`, 3. creating a `llvm_local` directory under tensorflow main directory, inside which was the content extracted from downloaded llvm.tar.gz and a custom `WORKSPACE` file as you had done. Didn't work. Can you please provide more details on how you did it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Same issue as @Turtlelzzy.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand Bazel but it seems like it offers this kind of functionality more or less out of the box. I found the following to work for XLA, which is actually from a [guide from TensorFlow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/compiler/mlir/README.md#using-local-llvm-repo):

1. Clone the LLVM repository and prepare it to be used by Bazel:

   ```bash
   LLVM_SRC=... # this the path to the LLVM local source directory you intend to use.
   touch ${LLVM_SRC}/BUILD.bazel ${LLVM_SRC}/WORKSPACE
   ```
2. Tell Bazel to use that folder for its LLVM dependency. You have two options:

   1. In the command line to Bazel:

      ```bash
      bazel build --override_repository="llvm-raw=${LLVM_SRC}" \
        -c opt tensorflow/compiler/mlir:tf-opt
      ```
   2. Add the following to the `WORKPLACE` file of the top-level Bazel project, then invoke Bazel as you normally would:

      ```
      local_repository(
         name = "llvm-raw",
         path = "/path/to/git/llvm-project",
      )
      ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the http server function of python to build a local file server, like:

> python3 -m http.server

Then edit the file "tensorflow/workspace.bzl"

```
tf_http_archive(
      name = "llvm",
      urls = [
          "https://mirror.bazel.build/**/195a164675af86f390f9816e53291013d1b551d7.tar.gz",
          "http://localhost:8000/195a164675af86f390f9816e53291013d1b551d7.tar.gz",
          "https://github.com/**/195a164675af86f390f9816e53291013d1b551d7.tar.gz",
      ],
      sha256 = "57a8333f8e6095d49f1e597ca18e591aba8a89d417f4b58bceffc5fe1ffcc02b",
      strip_prefix = "llvm-195a164675af86f390f9816e53291013d1b551d7",
      build_file = str(Label("//third_party/llvm:llvm.BUILD")),
  )
```

Add one local file path in the middle line of urls, and then rebuild it again.